# How to fix VMware fusion to import existing machine ( cloudera ) grayed out ?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, vmware

How to open the VMWare fusion with existing machine ?

Anybody succesfully install cloudera machine in VMWare in Yosemite ? Once I am trying to import the virtual machine file it grayed out .. any recommendation would be great.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In vmware fusion , you click file -> open  -> select a (.vmx) file in your cloudera

Answer (score 4):

If the files are already located in your Virtualbox Machines folder and the vm files are already unzipped and in the correct format, then the issue could be that you are using the `import` command instead of the `open` command. I ran into this issue and simply using the open command solved it.

Answer (score 2):

Cloudera VM images are in zip format, some thing like:

```
cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.4.0-0-vmware.zip
```

unzip it by double click; and you will have a folder named:

```
cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.4.0-0-vmware
```

then rename the folder to:

```
cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.4.0-0-vmware.vmwarevm
```

and accept the warning. After that you can open the VM folder by double clicking and it will be opened in the VMware Fusion, or you can move the folder to `~/Document/Virtual Machines` and then import it into the VMware Fusion.

**Note:** Consider defining appropriate memory to the virtual machine. The default is 4GB. If you run it with defaults and your Mac memory is low, it will not be started (no notifications will be shown).